# MySQL LIKE search with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, search, model, relationships

I'm trying to implement simple search functionality to my CakePHP application. I want users to be able to search based on a members first name, last name and the skills the member has.

My models are associated like this:

```
User ---hasOne---> Profile ---HABTM---> Skill
```

So a user has one profile, and a profile can have many skills and a skill can belong to many profiles. These relationships are set up correctly.

I've managed to get a basic first name search working by doing this:

```
public function memberList() {
    if(isset($this->request->data['User']['query'])) {
        // The user is searching, change the conditions of the retrieval
        $q = $this->request->data['User']['query'];

        $this->paginate = array(
            'conditions' => array('Profile.firstname LIKE' => "%$q%")
        );
    }

    // Retrieve member list
    $this->set('users', $this->paginate('User'));
}
```

However, there are two things I need help with. One is how to do an `OR` in the query. Because I want to search for the firstname and lastname, I need to do `Profile.firstname LIKE %$q% OR Profile.lastname LIKE %$q%`. How can I achieve that with the `conditions` parameter of the pagination call?

The second problem is searching by a users skills. Because `Skill` has a relationship with `Profile` instead of `User`, I don't get any skills returned by the find call to my `User` model. Is there a way I can change this so a user's profile's skills are returned? And if I get that far, how am I going to combine that with the firstname and lastname search without calling `$this->paginate` twice?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Your first question is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700288/cakephp-search-with-and-and-or-conditions?rq=1

Comment: Your first question is answered already, and your second is covered in your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851898/retrieving-data-through-two-model-relationships