# Retrieving data through two model relationships

Tags: php, cakephp, model, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm trying to retrieve some data through two model relationships with CakePHP. The models and their associations are as follows:

```
User hasOne Profile HABTM Skill
```

I would like the user's skills to be returned when I do a `find()` operation on the User model, and right now it isn't returned. Here's my find call which is being executed against the `User` model:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'OR' => array(
            'Profile.firstname LIKE' => "%$q%",
            'Profile.lastname LIKE' => "%$q%"
        )
    )
);
```

It's returning user data and profile data, but not any skill data. I tried setting `recursive` to `2` or `3`, but that doesn't help either. The only way I can get skill data is if I run `find()` against the `Profile` model, but I can't do that. For clarification here's the relevant models and their relationships:

```
// app/Model/User.php
class User extends AppModel {
    public $hasOne = 'Profile';
}

// app/Model/Profile.php
class Profile extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = 'User';
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = 'Skill';

// app/Model/Skill.php
class Skill extends AppModel {
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = 'Profile';
```

Can anyone help me get the users skills when retrieving user data? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CakePHP's Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).  Your find will then look something like this:

```
$this->User->find('all',array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'OR' => array(
            'Profile.firstname LIKE' => "%$q%",
            'Profile.lastname LIKE' => "%$q%"
        )
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        'Profile' => array(
            'Skill'
        )
    )
));
```

MUCH simpler, easier to read, and voila - you get the data you want without needing to use the dreaded 'recursive'.